How to add OSGI subsystem in Wildfly 25.x
i know OSGI support has been deprecated and discontinued in recent versions of wildfly. However i need it for our legacy application. Please help me with the required steps/configuration/jars to add osgi subsystem manually in Wildfly 25.x version.

give more detail to your question, does your application uses java ee specs if so which version, which version of wildfly currently being used? which version of java? so we can at least give suggestions.

There is no official OSGi subsystem for WildFly, neither I am aware of a maintained community one.

Thanks, guys, for responding. I have figured it out. :)
